# I don't get Response in my microservice(dotnet core 2 with postgresql) deployment docker

Tags: .net, postgresql, docker, .net-core, rancher

I am trying to make the deploy of my microservice in docker, but I have a problem with the petitions, I made the MS in dotnet core 2 with postgresql in Ubuntu 16.04. I don't know if the error is the dockerfile or the docker-compose.yml or the deploy. I have these files like this:

#### dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-sdk
WORKDIR /rooms_ms

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
#RUN dotnet ef database update
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "out/rooms_ms.dll"]
```

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
  rooms_ms:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: dockerfile
    environment:
      DB_CONNECTION_STRING: "host=postgres_image;port=5432;
        database=2E_room_db;username=username;password=password"
  rooms_db:
    image: postgres:alpine
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: "username"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "password"
      POSTGRES_DB: "2E_room_db"
```

#### terminal

```
~/Documents/room_ms$ docker-compose up
Starting roomms_rooms_db_1 ... 
Recreating roomms_rooms_ms_1 ... done
Attaching to roomms_rooms_db_1, roomms_rooms_ms_1
rooms_db_1  | 2018-03-19 05:12:21.281 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
rooms_db_1  | 2018-03-19 05:12:21.281 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
rooms_ms_1  | warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
rooms_ms_1  |       No XML encryptor configured. Key {c7c3f612-32d0-454c-9501-e51dc159e9b4} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
rooms_ms_1  | Hosting environment: Production
rooms_db_1  | 2018-03-19 05:12:21.703 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
rooms_ms_1  | Content root path: /rooms_ms
rooms_ms_1  | Now listening on: http://localhost:4040
rooms_db_1  | 2018-03-19 05:12:23.579 UTC [17] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2018-03-19 05:08:59 UTC
```

#### Postman

[postman response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSlHT.png)

#### Docker rancher

[rancher node with the microservice and database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9LP4.png)

I hope you can help me with this problem, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

your docker file is configured to use port 5432 and your postman invokes 4040

Comment: you are partially right about missing expose port 4040. But 5432 belongs to the database service, not the app.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the screenshot of rancher, both of the containers are shown under the "Standalone" section which makes me infer that the above yaml file was not used while creating a "Stack" in Rancher.

Look at the postman screenshot, you are trying to access port 4040. I believe the service `rooms_ms` is listening on this port but it's not exposed on the host. The same is evident in the docker-compose.yml file too. There is no ports section for `rooms_ms` service.

The following docker-compose file should fix the problem for you:

```
version: '2'
services:
  rooms_ms:
  ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: dockerfile
    environment:
      DB_CONNECTION_STRING: "host=postgres_image;port=5432;
        database=2E_room_db;username=username;password=password"
  rooms_db:
    image: postgres:alpine
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: "username"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "password"
      POSTGRES_DB: "2E_room_db"
```

Also just wanted to point out you are exposing/publish the db port on the host which is not needed for your `rooms_ms` service to access the db.